# Neo4j drop constraint if it does exist

Tags: neo4j, cypher, neo4j-bolt

Is there any way of dropping a constraint only if it exists through a query? I am using the bolt driver for javascript.

I initially thought I'll just catch the error, but the error I get is not clear enough:

```
{"code":"Neo.DatabaseError.Schema.ConstraintDropFailed"}
{ Error: An unexpected failure occurred, see details in the database logs, reference number .... }
```

In the logs I indeed get:

```
Unable to drop CONSTRAINT ... No such constraint CONSTRAINT
```

But I don't want to open the log programmatically and parse it.

Is there any way of dropping the constraint only if it exists? I haven't found anything useful.

The only thing that I can think of is trying first to create two nodes that would conflict with the constraint (which returns a more clear error), but I'd prefer something cleaner.

Comment: are you are dropping and then creating new constraints ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add `IF EXISTS` to the end of the statement:

```
DROP CONSTRAINT SOME_CONSTRAIN IF EXISTS
```

official documentation: https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-manual/5/constraints/examples/#administration-constraints-drop-a-non-existing-constraint

Answer (score 1):

If you know all the indexes and constraints that you want, you can use the apoc procedure [apoc.schema.assert](https://neo4j-contrib.github.io/neo4j-apoc-procedures/#_schema) to make that they exist and that all other existing indexes and constraints are dropped.

An example of how to use this procedure is part of this [doc section](https://neo4j-contrib.github.io/neo4j-apoc-procedures/#_cassandra_example). Here is a snippet showing a call to the procedure and the results:

```
Let’s create some indexes and constraints, note that other indexes and constraints will be dropped by this.

CALL apoc.schema.assert(
  {Track:['title','length']},
  {Artist:['name'],Track:['id'],Genre:['name']});

╒════════════╤═══════╤══════╤═══════╕
│label       │key    │unique│action │
╞════════════╪═══════╪══════╪═══════╡
│Track       │title  │false │CREATED│
├────────────┼───────┼──────┼───────┤
│Track       │length │false │CREATED│
├────────────┼───────┼──────┼───────┤
│Artist      │name   │true  │CREATED│
├────────────┼───────┼──────┼───────┤
│Genre       │name   │true  │CREATED│
├────────────┼───────┼──────┼───────┤
│Track       │id     │true  │CREATED│
└────────────┴───────┴──────┴───────┘
```

Comment: but... what if... you _don't_ know all those constraints and indexes in advance?